# HLS playback on Google Home

Tags: streaming, http-live-streaming, google-home

I currently have an alexa app in development that plays HLS audio files that I want to recreate on the google home.  I'm not however to find any info on HLS audio playback on the google home and will not be able to convert them to mp3 or ogg. Is there any solution or documentation for hls files?

Comment: cricket... cricket...

Comment: Did you ever find out whether Google Home supported HLS audio playback?

Comment: @superjonbot did you find any solution?